# Cloning of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a button which label is "save & copy" doing save the current object (@student) and redirect it back to new action and these new contains all the previous object attributes. I have stucked how to populate previous values.

Is ROR provide any such method to make clone of object.

Comment: have you tried `@student.clone`?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails provides the `clone` method, which creates a shallow clone of the object. In your case, you could use it like that:

```
@previous_student = @student.clone
```

The documentation of the `clone` method states:

> Returns a clone of the record that
>   hasn’t been assigned an id yet and is
>   treated as a new record. Note that
>   this is a “shallow” clone: it copies
>   the object’s attributes only, not its
>   associations. The extent of a “deep”
>   clone is application-specific and is
>   therefore left to the application to
>   implement according to its need.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001848

As stated in the documentation, you should maybe override the `clone` method, to implement your own cloning, if you use associations in the `Student` model.

Cheers